# facebook api key problems php

Tags: php, facebook

I get an invalid API key which is definitly correct- no whitespaces or nothing- im stuck

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'FacebookRestClientException' with message 'Invalid API key' in /home/maxer/domains/follor.com/public_html/xmasapp/facebook/php/facebookapi_php5_restlib.php:3112 Stack trace: #0 /home/maxer/domains/follor.com/public_html/xmasapp/facebook/php/facebookapi_php5_restlib.php(309): FacebookRestClient->call_method('facebook.auth.g...', Array) #1 /home/maxer/domains/follor.com/public_html/xmasapp/facebook/php/facebook.php(206): FacebookRestClient->auth_getSession('c6b7baef6d609ba...', false) #2 /home/maxer/domains/follor.com/public_html/xmasapp/facebook/php/facebook.php(167): Facebook->do_get_session('c6b7baef6d609ba...') #3 /home/maxer/domains/follor.com/public_html/xmasapp/facebook/php/facebook.php(68): Facebook->validate_fb_params() #4 /home/maxer/domains/follor.com/public_html/xmasapp/index.php(15): Facebook->__construct('?99a8a43434baf7...', '?02365dce6ae555...') #5 {main} thrown in /home/maxer/domains/follor.com/public_html/xmasapp/facebook/php/facebookapi_php5_restlib.php on line 3112
```

Comment: Not sure if it would yield that error, but does your server run PHP5?

Comment: Is the key being used on the proper domain that you have whitelisted in your facebook app settings?

Comment: I just noticed, I doubt the API key should start with `?`

Answer (score 0):

Did you give correct APP_KEY, APP_SECRET and APP_ID variables. Because all these are important for correctness of the output.

I write something like and it works fine

$fbconfig['appid' ]  = "###########";

```
$fbconfig['api'   ]  = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$fbconfig['secret']  = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";


try{
    include_once "facebook.php";
}
catch(Exception $o){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($o);
    echo '</pre>';
}
// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
  'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
  'cookie' => true,
));
```